# tengo un problema con crystal report que no se encuentra el informe

Tags: c#

este es el mensaje pero también tengo la referencias agregada[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: esta es la excepción]
[image: también tengo la referencia he instalado CRforVS6413SP32_0-80007712]

[image: me manda a este cogigo]